# Three.js Animation in Canvas doesn't resize properly in Vue Application

Tags: javascript, vue.js, three.js

I'm currently trying to learn Three.js and I'm doing it inside a Vue.js component,
this is my code:

```
<script>
import * as THREE from "three";

export default {
  name: "Scene",
  mounted() {
    this.initThree();
  },
  methods: {
    initThree() {
      this.canvas = document.getElementById("background");

      this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
      this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, 2, 0.1, 1000);

      this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        canvas: this.canvas,
        alpha: true,
        antialias: true,
      });
      this.renderer.setSize(this.canvas.clientWidth, this.canvas.clientHeight);

      let geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);

      this.light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
      this.light.position.set(4, -2, 2);
      this.scene.add(this.light);

      this.camera.position.z = 2;

      this.cubes = [
        this.makeInstance(geometry, 0x44aa88, 0),
        this.makeInstance(geometry, 0x8844aa, -2),
        this.makeInstance(geometry, 0xaa8844, 2),
      ];

      this.animate();
    },

    animate() {
      this.cubes.forEach((cube) => {
        cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
      });
      this.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize();
      this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
      requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
    },

    resizeCanvasToDisplaySize() {
      const canvas = this.renderer.domElement;
      // look up the size the canvas is being displayed
      const width = canvas.clientWidth;
      const height = canvas.clientHeight;

      if (canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height) {
        this.renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
        this.camera.aspect = width / height;
        this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
      }
    },

    makeInstance(geometry, color, x) {
      const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color });

      const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
      this.scene.add(cube);

      cube.position.x = x;

      return cube;
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
canvas {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

If I resize the window to a smaller size than the initial size (the sizewhen the page was loaded), in developer tools on chrome, it works, the canvas width and height is getting changed properly. If I make the size bigger than the initial size it stays the same and doesn't scale at all. Also the scaling just works in dev tools not in the actual window.

Comment: I suggest you do it differently and register an event listener to the `resize` event. You can then use the same implementation like in this basic example: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_cube

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic in your resize function is flawed. You're essentially getting the curent width: `const width = canvas.clientWidth;` and then you're circularly assigning it back to where you got it from. You're sort of doing the same as this:

```
width = canvas.width;
canvas.width = width;
```

You should use the standard method used in all Three.js examples. Instead of checking for resize on each `animate()` frame, just set an event listener for when the window resizes, and then use the window's size to set the canvas' dimensions:

```js
window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

function onWindowResize() {
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, looking at it now the question seems kinda silly, the function truly didn't make a lot of sense ^^